# How to plot 2D or 3D graph using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in reading the following data file into Python and separate the data into variables keeping in mind each variable is one column and the radiance (which is the last variable) has many columns. After separating them graph a 2D graph.

I would like it much if you'd show me how to put these variables in columns and radians in many columns.You can pick any arbitrary name for many columns.

```
1. 165.08  75.16 200.07 18.08  0.36 561556726 1 -9.034E-08  1.121E-06  9.695E-07  7.981E-07  1.575E-05  2.284E-06  1.912E-06  1.998E-06  2.053E-06  2.116E-06  2.149E-06  2.197E-06  2.209E-06  2.163E-06  2.149E-06  2.218E-06  2.166E-06  2.190E-06  2.185E-06  2.105E-06  2.110E-06  2.086E-06  2.053E-06  1.996E-06  2.020E-06  1.992E-06  1.905E-06  1.897E-06  1.784E-06  1.697E-06  1.718E-06  1.602E-06  1.579E-06  1.536E-06  1.480E-06  1.415E-06  1.345E-06  1.341E-06  1.274E-06  1.249E-06  1.204E-06  1.170E-06  1.139E-06  1.119E-06  1.032E-06  9.872E-07  8.550E-07  6.789E-07  6.203E-07  6.594E-07  5.504E-07  5.858E-07  6.771E-07  7.255E-07  6.678E-07  6.082E-07  5.895E-07  5.551E-07  5.206E-07  5.001E-07  4.303E-07  4.685E-07  3.865E-07  4.051E-07  3.697E-07  3.725E-07  3.390E-07  3.316E-07  2.626E-07  2.794E-07  2.775E-07  2.738E-07  2.654E-07  2.272E-07  2.030E-07  2.040E-07  2.272E-07  1.816E-07  1.565E-07  1.714E-07  1.267E-07  1.201E-07  1.807E-07  1.220E-07  1.108E-07  1.583E-07  1.248E-07  1.220E-07  8.661E-08  1.052E-07  1.099E-07  9.499E-08  1.341E-07  8.568E-08  5.588E-08  5.867E-08  6.333E-08  7.357E-08  7.078E-08  2.328E-08  5.495E-08  6.147E-08  6.519E-08  2.701E-08  3.353E-08  9.499E-08  3.818E-08  5.681E-08  8.196E-08  3.539E-08  5.309E-08  1.024E-08  5.029E-08  8.009E-08  4.657E-08
```

Comment: You need to provide a little more context. First of all I can't understand your data. How many columns do you want? What goes to which column? Which data are the radians? How many columns and according to what do you want us to split the radians? And please provide us with a bit info on what variables exactly you want plotted (the values of one column, one column compared to another, etc).

Comment: Plotting such small numbers? What do these represent?

Comment: Many columns for the variables and only one columns for radians ( radians are the ones at the last , the last variables ) .They represent maps . You can pick any arbitrary value to compare columns.

Answer (score 2):

First let's store your data in a variable:

```
a = '165.08 75.16 200.07 18.08 0.36 561556726 1 -9.034E-08 1.121E-06 9.695E-07 7.981E-07 1.575E-05 2.284E-06 1.912E-06 1.998E-06 2.053E-06 2.116E-06 2.149E-06 2.197E-06 2.209E-06 2.163E-06 2.149E-06 2.218E-06 2.166E-06 2.190E-06 2.185E-06 2.105E-06 2.110E-06 2.086E-06 2.053E-06 1.996E-06 2.020E-06 1.992E-06 1.905E-06 1.897E-06 1.784E-06 1.697E-06 1.718E-06 1.602E-06 1.579E-06 1.536E-06 1.480E-06 1.415E-06 1.345E-06 1.341E-06 1.274E-06 1.249E-06 1.204E-06 1.170E-06 1.139E-06 1.119E-06 1.032E-06 9.872E-07 8.550E-07 6.789E-07 6.203E-07 6.594E-07 5.504E-07 5.858E-07 6.771E-07 7.255E-07 6.678E-07 6.082E-07 5.895E-07 5.551E-07 5.206E-07 5.001E-07 4.303E-07 4.685E-07 3.865E-07 4.051E-07 3.697E-07 3.725E-07 3.390E-07 3.316E-07 2.626E-07 2.794E-07 2.775E-07 2.738E-07 2.654E-07 2.272E-07 2.030E-07 2.040E-07 2.272E-07 1.816E-07 1.565E-07 1.714E-07 1.267E-07 1.201E-07 1.807E-07 1.220E-07 1.108E-07 1.583E-07 1.248E-07 1.220E-07 8.661E-08 1.052E-07 1.099E-07 9.499E-08 1.341E-07 8.568E-08 5.588E-08 5.867E-08 6.333E-08 7.357E-08 7.078E-08 2.328E-08 5.495E-08 6.147E-08 6.519E-08 2.701E-08 3.353E-08 9.499E-08 3.818E-08 5.681E-08 8.196E-08 3.539E-08 5.309E-08 1.024E-08 5.029E-08 8.009E-08 4.657E-08 '
```

Then we'll split this string and convert each number to float.

```
a = [float(x) for x in a.split()]
```

Finally, we'll plot these points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a[7:])  # I don't plot the first 7 numbers as they are 
                 # really high and would dominate the gragh
                 # feel free to remove the square brackets
                 # if you want all the points to be plotted
```

Now if you want to view the plot add `plt.show()` and if you want to save it just type `plt.savefig('aa.png', bbox_inches='tight')`.

With these I get the following image:

[image]

Comment: Yes very helpful ,please update me with needed information so I can learn how you managed to get it .Thanks

Comment: check it out if this seems helpful to you